# Using LaTeX in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, latex

I try to make a table with a title in Python using LaTeX.

The following code creates a figure with a title, as I want the title to be.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

s1="a_b_c"
s2=r'''\begin{tabular}{ c | c | c } & 1 & 2 \\\hline 1 & 1 & 2 \\\hline 2 & 2 & 4 \end{tabular}'''

plt.figure(figsize=(4,5))
ax=plt.subplot2grid((1,1),(0,0))

ax.text(0.5,0.8,s1,ha="center",va="center",transform=ax.transAxes)

plt.show()
```

[image: right title]

But now I add two lines to the upper code which make the title wrong.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

s1="a_b_c"
s2=r'''\begin{tabular}{ c | c | c } & 1 & 2 \\\hline 1 & 1 & 2 \\\hline 2 & 2 & 4 \end{tabular}'''

plt.figure(figsize=(4,5))
ax=plt.subplot2grid((1,1),(0,0))

ax.text(0.5,0.8,s1,ha="center",va="center",transform=ax.transAxes)

###
plt.rc('text', usetex=True)
ax.text(0.3,0.2,s2,ha="left",va="bottom",transform=ax.transAxes,size=20)
###

plt.show()
```

[image]

What can I do to use LaTeX fonts and usual python fonts at the same time? Of course, without modifying the strings s1 and s2.

Answer (score 4):

All you need to do is add a few lines to your file:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.rc('text', usetex=True)
plt.rc('font', family='serif')
```

And you have LaTeX fonts!

To get the a_b_c working like you wanted, you need to do:

```
a_{b_c}
```

Or the b and c will be at the same level.

Comment: I tried this and it still looks like the second figure I posted.. my issue is the "a" with underscore "bc", I want it just to be "a_b_c" as in the first figure

Comment: Oh, ha, sorry, I misunderstood. Then it's your LaTeX that's wrong - you need to do a_{b_c} and it should be fine. I'll edit my answer.

Comment: actually, I hoped to do it without modifying the string... is there no other way?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the LaTeX function `\textit{a_b_c}` to write normal text.

Reference: https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/text_labels_and_annotations/tex_demo.html